# python3 trying to get multi-line input

Tags: python, input

I am trying to get multi-line input from a user as in like the body of a message. I don't want to use external scripts or line number amounts. This code below only stores the last line in BODY

```
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        BODY = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(BODY)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  You're rewriting the variable `BODY` in each iteration of the loop.  Therefore, when the loop is done, you'll only have the most recent assigned value.

Comment: Also, does `contents` not hold the input at the end of the loop?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem of this code. contents has user's input.

Comment: You should append the `contents` inside `try` block, because the variable `BODY`'s value will change every time user inputs new one. You can do that and use `join` after it breaks out of the `while` block instead.

Comment: Daniel, you make a lot of sense but I am not sure how to keep from rewriting BODY. If it is not in the while loop, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @DhanaD. I tried your idea and still no dice. I can't put the code here, too long? so here is a pastebin link

https://pastebin.com/Zqegjge0

Answer (score 0):

This will keep appending the user's input to `contents`

```
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        BODY = input()
        contents.append(BODY)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, Primus, but the code did not change the results.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Here is the finished bit of code

```
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        BODY = input()
        contents.append(BODY)
    except EOFError:
        break

text = '\n'.join(contents)

print(text)
```

Comment: Gotcha! Putting the `append` inside `try` and the `join` outside the `while` block works.